# archive file and SQLite access

Tags: android, archive

we are trying to develop a set of common functionalities into .aar in android project. We have a concern that, can we access data from database attached in the main application bundle ?

Does android limit and persistent storage functions for .aar type of projects ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

.aar is just a library, so you can do anything you could do in the app which uses the library.